# ChiSquare is zero even though the values are not identical

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, excel

I am running a Chisquare test using CHIDIST function in Excel. My observed and expected values are not identical however i get result 0 (zero). There are 75 observed values so I am using 74 freedom points. Not sure what I am doing wrong, any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The [description](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/chidist-function-c90d0fbc-5b56-4f5f-ab57-34af1bf6897e) of the `CHIDIST` Excel function says:

> Returns the right-tailed probability of the chi-squared distribution. The $\chi^2$ distribution is associated with a $\chi^2$ test. Use the $\chi^2$ test to compare observed and expected values.

This means that the *p-value* displayed by the function will be lower when the observed valuer are **far away** from the expected ones; and the *p-value* will be $1$ if the observed values match exactly the expected values. Therefore, since you are getting a very small *p-value* (displayed as zero due to the rounding done by Excel), I deduct that your data is distinct from the expected distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did the chi square test as sum of (observed-expected)^2/expected and the number i got is quite big - around 2,700,000 which I am not sure if makes sense. Regarding the rounding I don't know how small the number would be for excel or numbers in mac to not show it as I tried upto 30decimals and still result is zero. Is there any way to see the actual number? I

Comment: @DimitrisM : 2.7 million is a lot! Are you sure you haven't made a mistake? For 74 degrees of freedom, a *p-value* of $0.001$ would be attained for $\chi^2$ around $117$; and a *p-value* of $10^{-30}$ would be attained for $\chi^2$ around $310$.

Comment: It does seem a lot to me also but not sure where I got it wrong. I calculate x square by summing the squared differences of observed minus expected values and dividing the result by expected value, for each row.

Comment: The link to the data I am using is this if you want to have a look. The observed/estimated values are flu count incidents per US county. https://github.com/DimitrisMertikas/Chisquaretesting

Comment: @DimitrisM: I've checked your data and I got $\chi^2 = 2\ 189 \ 770.58$ for $df=74$. So, It's natural to have such a low *p-value*. Looking at the data, you see counties with an incidence of nearly $43\%$, and others with incidences of $0.01\%$, thus, the *p-value* is telling that there are significant differences between counties, which is according to what is observed.